# VNC viewer for iPhone, cotvnc or libvncclient

Tags: iphone, objective-c, vnc

I am working on a VNC viewer application for iPhone, and connecting it to tightVNCServer. I have discovered that I can either:

- Modify [COTVNC](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=386447&group_id=64347) to build my own version for iPhone
- Use C-based libvncclient library and bind it with Objective-C code

Which solution will provide the most features supported by tightVNCServer, such as file transfer, etc ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to quickly end your debate : both are licensed under the GPL license. And GPL-licensed code is not allowed on the AppStore (remember how Apple pulled VLC off of the store ?). So your choice has to be "none", unless you're ready to see countless hours of work go down the drain...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/licensing.php) commerical license for a fast solution. It is not under GPL license.

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in Stack Overflow.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rahul - I think this is a case where a bad question generated answers that violate SO's policies (But its an otherwise good answer to the question at hand). We should probably move against the question.

Comment: I would agree with you, but the fact that this answer contains only a link still remains valid. May be we should reconsider the question qualifying to be put here.